# Does anyone has an experiences with building Google/Talkback?

Tags: android, android-ndk

In order to contribute to Google/Talkback, I was adding some code to my fork of the google/talkback repository, and would like to build, and test it.
I tryed it from the latst Debian, installing android-sdk using:

```
$ sudo apt-get update -y
$ sudo apt-get install android-sdk -y
```

After the SDK installation, I had downloaded the ndk, and use this to extract:

```
$ sudo unzip android-ndk.zip -d /usr/lib/android-ndk
```

Then, I set the following variables:

```
$ extract ANDROID_SDK /usr/lib/android-sdk
$extract ANDROID_NDK /usr/lib/android-ndk
$ extract JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

But, when I clone the talkback from my fork using:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/daremc86/talkback
```

to /home directory, and when try:

```
./build.sh
```

It gives me the error that cannot find /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager to accept licenses.
I know that tghe sdkmanager is a part of cmdline-tools, but where to extract them, and how to set the variable?
In ./build.sh writes that sdkmanager is located at ANDROID_SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager

I really want to test my implementation into Talback, and please help.

Best regards,

Darko

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract both sdkmanager and ndk where ever you wanted. You can set the requied variables.

```
"export ANDROID_SDK=~/LOCATION_TO_SDK"
"export ANDROID_NDK=~/LOCATION_TO_SDK/ndk/20.1.5948944/"
```

you can also create a local.properties file with below 2 fields

```
sdk.dir=LOCATION_TO\sdk
ndk.dir=LOCATION_TO_NDK\sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393
```